# R tcltk: Using a single scrollbar for multiple listboxes

Tags: r, listbox, scrollbar, tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm currently working on a problem with having to implement a scrollbar that scrolls multiple listboxes together in R. The R-functions for accessing options (tkset/tkcget) work a little differently than they do in perl, so I sadly can't just rewrite those examples.

I would be thankful for getting some pointers on how to do this in R. I've had no luck with inputting .Tcl command directly either, because I don't fully understand the way that scrollbars and widgets are junctioned yet.

Thanks in advance!